# How do I find out the final position and distance of a point from the origin?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simulation where n number of particles are interacting gravitationally. I usually have to take n anywhere between 1,000 and 1,000,000,000 but I tend to take the numbers from the lower end.
supposing n = 1000, I run the simulation for about 3 seconds and I get a 2D plot of particles mostly clustered in the centre with some wayward ones.

The question now is to find out the distance between the origin and each particle.
I don't know what final positions the particles are taking and I have no way to get the distance.

Is there a way to get find the distance between each particle and the origin?

Comment: You do not know the position of a particle, but you do have a 2D plot of the position of the particles?

Comment: The positions are randomly generated and then the particles start moving around when they feel each other's gravitational influence. At the end of the simulation, an image is created where the particles are at random positions. I hope this clears the confusion

Comment: You could extract the location from the 2D plot using for example openCV. However if the image is created it might be more straightforward to look into how the image is created and extract the locations from there.